# Control color of legend elements that are not colour guides in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using a ggplot2 theme with a black background, can one control the legend colour for guides other than the colour guide so that things are not plotted in black?  If so, how?

```
library(ggplot2) # needs to be 0.9.3 for this theme
data(iris)       # included with ggplot2

theme_black<- function (base_size = 16, base_family = ""){
    theme_minimal() %+replace% 
        theme(
              line = element_line(colour = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, 
                        lineend = "butt"), 
              rect = element_rect(fill = "white", 
                        colour = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = 1), 
              text = element_text(family = base_family, 
                        face = "plain", colour = "white", size = base_size,
                        angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, hjust = 0, vjust = 0),
              plot.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'black'),
              plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
              panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "white"), 
              panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey20", size = 0.2), 
              panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey5", size = 0.5),
              strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey30", colour = "grey30")
             )
    }

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape=Species,
       colour=Petal.Length))+geom_point()+theme_black()+
       scale_colour_gradient(low = "purple", high = "white")
```

As you can see, the default colour for the shape part of the legend has not been changed, so it is invisible and one cannot tell which species is which:

[image]

The only solution I have right now is to change the legend.background colour, but this is a waste of ink and ugly.

Comment: Here is a partial fix: `+ guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour="white")))`. Unfortunately, `theme()` cannot be used to change things like the default point color.

Comment: Thanks for this response (+1).  I think it would be worth adding as an answer: I would certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add two extra `geom_point`s, the logic would be:

plot white points for the legend, cover them with black points with no legend, then plot your coloured points with no legend,e.g.

```
geom_point(colour="white",size=1) + 
geom_point(colour="black",size=3,show_guide=FALSE) +
geom_point(show_guide=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  (Why would you need the black geom_point since the top one covers the white one anyway? Have you noticed cases where white shows on the edges?) ...   I am hoping that there is a solution in which changing themes does not force us to add extra layers to our code.

Comment: yeah ive noticed when plotting incomplete coverage of points. As long as the size is different it will be ok and maybe skip the black (i suppose the black point option is there if you dont want to be constrained in the point sizes for your coloued points)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer seems to be that there is no perfect way to do this.

We can add hidden layers with shape guides as per @user1317221_G's answer, which I accepted.  But it is extra computation and if we save as pdf, I expect these hidden layers will be present.

Alternatively, we can override the shape guide's colour, as @bdemarest suggests in comments:

```
+ guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour="white"))
```

But this still forces us to add theme-specific code beyond just the +theme_black()

I've implemented a slightly more elaborate version of this because I set a default theme for the session depending on whether I am making plots for paper (grey/white background) or screen (black background).  So my approach is to run something along these lines early in the session:

```
 set_theme(theme_black); defaultcol = "white" # for slides
 # or
 set_theme(theme_bw); defaultcol = "black"    # for paper
```

followed by a ggplot() that includes this:

```
+ guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=defaultcol))
```

This has the advantage of minimizing the need for theme-specific adjustments to plots, though it is not as good as being able to control the default ggplot2 colour with a theme.